# Printing details about file stream objects in gdb - c++

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have function whose signature is something like so:

```
void someFunc(ifstream ifile) {
```

This function is embedded deep within the code. When I am debugging this code with ddd, how can I get the name of the file from the ifstream object. Trying the following:
`p ifile`  or

```
ptype ifile
```

leads to a mountain of information being dumped. Is there a way to get the filename that ifile is a stream to?

Thanks,
Sriram.

Comment: @Nawaz: ptype prints the type of a variable in ddd. so, for double a, ptype a gives double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the filename that ifile is a stream to?

No way. That's not possible.

`std::ifstream` doesn't store the filename, neither does it provide any *get* function to get the filename. Thus, you cannot get it, given an object of type `std::ifstream`.

---

If you really need to know the filename inside the function (and cannot change the function signature), then you can maintain a *global* lookup table (or preferably `std::map`) and add an entry whenever you open a file, something like this:

```
std::map<std::ifstream*, const char*> g_stream_file_pairs;

std::ifstream ifile("xyz/abc/filename.txt");
g_stream_file_pairs.insert(std::make_pair(&ifile, ""xyz/abc/filename.txt"));


void someFunc(std::ifstream & ifile) 
{ 
       const char* filename = g_stream_file_pairs[&ifile];
       //...
}
```

Comment: does the above hold true for all file pointers? Any specific reason why the designers chose to omit this feature from the language?

Comment: @Sriram: What do you mean by *file pointers*? My answer depends on it, so please clarify that.

Comment: As in ofstream, ifstream etc. Maybe I should have written file stream objects?

Comment: @Sriram: yeah.. the correct terminology is `file stream objects`.

Comment: @Sriram: Now the answer to your question: if you want it to work with all types of file stream, then you can simply use `void*` for storing the addresses the objects, so define `std::map<void*, const char*>`. After all, we're storing the addresses, we're not interested in the actual type of the object. And `std::ifstream*` , `std::ofstream*` etc can convert into `void*` implicitly. That should work.